# Computing/using RSA modulus without knowing its factors

Tags: rsa, protocol-design

There are some protocols, e.g. [this](http://www.ghassankarame.com/OPOR.pdf), that require parties to compute/use RSA modulus: $N$ without knowing it's factors or $\phi(N)$.

One way of doing it is to use a trusted party.

**Question**: Is there any other way of generating/using $N$ in the above schemes without using a trusted party? (If yes, can you refer me to some papers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this with secure multiparty computation. There are several papers about this problem, but the most recent state of the art is:

> Tore Kasper Frederiksen and Yehuda Lindell and Valery Osheter and Benny Pinkas: [Fast Distributed RSA Key Generation for Semi-Honest and Malicious Adversaries](https://ia.cr/2018/577)